# Making a list with temporal variables and choose random one of those elements

Tags: list, variables, random, netlogo

Hi i am doing a model and i need to make a list of elements using the values of a temporal variable. This is the code that i have used to define my temporal variables

```
to react
  ask  cells
   [
   let Ai1 count turtles with [color = blue and xcor < -13 and ycor > -26] 
   let Ai2 count turtles with [color = blue and xcor < -13 and ycor < -27] 
   let Ai3 count turtles with [color = blue and xcor > -12 and xcor < 11 and ycor > -26]
   let Ai4 count turtles with [color = blue and xcor > -12 and xcor < 11 and ycor < -26]
    let Ai5 count turtles with [color = blue and xcor > 11 and ycor > -26]
    let Ai6 count turtles with [color = blue and xcor > 11 and ycor < -26]
  let Aimax list  (Ai1 Ai2 Ai3 Ai4 Ai5 Ai6)
   set calories (44.5 * random Aimax)
     ]
  end
```

So i need to make a list of the Ai1...Ai6 values and then choose ramdomly one of this 6 values to use it in the next multiplication of the temporal variable Aimax so is posible to do that? If i use the command random it can be used in lists? Tks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

[`one-of`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#one-of) will pick a random item from a list:

```
set calories (44.5 * one-of Aimax)
```

Comment: Thanks i tought that one-of only works with turtles and patches not with any kind of agentlist. Any suggestion to agroup the variables? because the command "list" only work with constants not with a tempoeal variables.

Comment: I figure it out how to make the list . I use the "sentence" command to agroup 3 variables first grouping 2 temproal variables and then with another variable . I reapt this  with the other 3 temporal variales and finally joined them to make a list of the 6 temporal variables. I do it in this way beacause it sems that with this command you can´t join a list of 2 items with other with more items, thats why i need to make 2 list of the same amount of items (3) and use "sentence" to group them.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it that way.  You are having each cell compute all the counts, which only need to be determined once.  You also repeated filter your turtles on the color blue.  If we stick with your bounds, we can write

```
to-report countblues
  let blues (turtles with [color = blue])
  let counts (list
    count blues with [xcor < -13 and ycor > -26] 
    count blues with [xcor < -13 and ycor < -27] 
    count blues with [xcor > -12 and xcor < 11 and ycor > -26]
    count blues with [xcor > -12 and xcor < 11 and ycor < -26]
    count blues with [xcor > 11 and ycor > -26]
    count blues with [xcor > 11 and ycor < -26]
    )
  report counts
end

to react
  let counts countblues
  ask  cells[
    set calories (44.5 * one-of counts)
  ]
end
```

Note that if you turtles never change colors you could turn `blues` into a global, although there would be small gain to that and each global has a cost in referential transparency.